# Scrollable GridView with fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gridview

I'm trying to make a scrollable gridview to `gv_RegionMaster`. I'm attaching database dynamically. I've also tried CSS with this. But yet not working.

I know that its' a repeated question but its not working with my code. Please let me know if one can help me out.

```
{
<script type="text/stylesheet">
.header
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow:scroll;
    max-height:500px;
    width:600px
}
</script>
    <asp:Button ID="btn_DisplayGrid" runat="server" Text="Click here"/>
    <br /><br />

   <div id="DivMainContent" visible="false" runat="server" align="center">

        <asp:GridView ID="gv_RegionMaster" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" Height="500px" Width="600px" style="overflow:auto">
            <HeaderStyle cssClass="header" BackColor="Gray"/>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: is there any need to write { Boundfield } in gridview?

Comment: I've solved scrolling by panel but still fixed header for runtime database is not done. Anybody can help me with that?